# Is there a way to validate the signature of JWT access token for Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How can I validate the signature of a JWT token for Team Services? Is there a public keys like https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs provided by Team Services which can be used to validate that token is signed by Team Services.

Comment: What's the propose to validate the signature of VSO JWT token?

Comment: Not find the key to validate that. How about sending the request and checking the result to validate JWT token?

Comment: JWT is the way for securely transmitting information between parties as a JSON object, if data has been modified during the transmission, the request will be failed.